# Elsa Workflow Approval Signals

Tags: elsa-workflows

I've implemented a document approval workflow using Elsa which uses email and signal_url to handle approval/rejection. This works as expected.

My problem is when a user clicks an embedded email link that has already been actioned by another user in their approval group. Elsa just redirects to a blank page '/signals/trigger/...' with an empty object [].

I'd like to notify the user that their signal has already been actioned. Is that possible?

I'm using Elsa 2.9.2 and the designer.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you approve or reject, the workflow finishes; when it's finished, it doesn't get triggered; you get an empty JSON array.

One way to get a response is to connect back to the fork activity so it keeps listening for the signal and you can set a variable to preserve the state and send the right message.

You'll need more changes than that or you keep receiving reminder emails. It's just to give you an idea. It really depends on your specific application.